# adding the .txt file's content in the body of the message in the mail of mailx command in linux

Tags: linux, server, alert, monitoring

I have written a script where i am storing the name of the top 10 processes which are using the greatest ram of the cpu with a command:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head >/etc/tmp/file.txt
```

Now I am attaching this file in the mailx command to send a mail with its body as content with the command:

```
echo -e "Warning, server memory is running low!\n\nFree memory: $free MB\n$file" | mailx -a "ALERT" -s "$subject" -r "$from" -c "$also_to" "$to"
```

this "subject" , "from", "also_to", "to" are some variables and have actual mailid defined in the shell script.

when I get receive the mail I get the content in a very rough order like the picture below that i have added.[that mail's pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8guA.png)

I want this content to of the file to be in proper format or if I could just send this txt file as an attachment, I made a whole study for sending the file as an attachment using the mailx command but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the `-a` option. You are supposed to use it to add a mail header (`Header: value`), not the single word "ALERT" like you did.

As to how to send the file as an attachment, I usually use the `-A` option with no trouble (at worst, I vaguely remember that sometimes I had to specify the file encoding so that accented characters are correctly displayed, but you don't need this with your ASCII file)

Comment: I have used -A but it did not work and with -A directly we have to name the file or mentioning the whole path of that file.